# 1 second connection times for localhost vs. nill connection times agains my IP 192.168.1.x

Tags: http, networking, web, jetty

I'm seeing an odd behavior connecting to a development webserver running on my local machine.

When I connect to http://192.168.1.14 (my ip) **everything loads fast** (sub 200ms for a page + 20 resources, an expected result).

When I connect to http://localhost I get **5 second load** times for the same page and what I see when I profile the page using Chrome is:

- 1st page, ~1 sec connection time (varies from 0.98 to 1.02), then loads fast
- The next 3 resources have a ~1 sec connection time then load fast.
- The next 6 then wait ~1 sec connection time (after the last group loaded) then load fast.
- This pattern repeats its self in batches of 6 resources until everything is loaded.

Any ideas on this? Where could the 1 sec connection time delay be coming from?

I'm referencing "Connection Time" from the resource profile graph provided in the Google Chrome Developer Tools. For example, one resource shows:

```
Proxy:      0ms
DNS Lookup: 1ms
Connecting: 1.00s
Sending:    0ms
Waiting:    3ms
Receiving:  2ms
```

Comment: Hmm, those links of yours don't seem to be working :-)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  I am running into it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently.

The problem was that I had configured a proxy server in Windows' proxy settings and every request went through the proxy even though I had explicitly enabled the option "Bypass proxy server for local addresses". Apparently this setting was not working or didn't do what I expected.

So I went ahead and configured an exception for `localhost` in the advanced proxy settings. Now everything from my development server loads pretty fast.

Comment: This may vary well have been the issue, as I'm not encountering it any more. However I was playing with proxy settings around that time. Thanks for the reply!!

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you try `127.0.0.1` directly? I imaging it *could* be the fact that something still has to translate `localhost` into `127.0.0.1` be it a DNS server or your /etc/hosts file or the yellow-pages service.

If `127.0.0.1` is fast, I would say it's a translation delay in which case the next step is to figure out what's doing the translation.

If it's slow, I'd be looking at the appserver or webserver logs. Apache, if that's what you're using, is one of the only two infinitely-configurable applications ever built, the other being Emacs, of course :-)

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is fast (120ms), so is 192.168.1.114, it's only when I use http://localhost I get slow load times (typically 4 seconds). DNS time in chrome is called out separately and doesn't show as any problem (not that I know how chrome is calculating these things though). The work around is simple enough, but it's very odd behavior. I tried profiling the application in eclipse and it shows no abnormal time spent on the server, it seems like it's all really in the connection. But I can't do a wireshark capture on localhost. I guess this is an OS issue really.

Comment: You may not be able to wireshark localhost but, if the request is going out to a DNS server, you can capture _that_. What are your actual DNS settings from `ipconfig /all` or `ifconfig`?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was adding a host file entry and referencing the local website through the host file entry. For some inexplicable reason, this rendered the page in real time.